# Jquery find text and change single cell value

Tags: jquery, html, replace, html-table

I've been trying to figure this out. I'm trying to use JQuery to find a cell with an exact value and then change the text in that exact cell without obliterating the rest of the table.

Here's a very simple HTML table:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Value 1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1234
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Value 1.1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        5678
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to find the cell that exactly matches "Value 1" and then change it to "Value TO THE MAX" without changing any other cells (so it can't accidently match the cell "Value 1.1")

My most recent/non-crashing attempt:

```
$("td:contains('Value 1')").text("Value 1.TO-THE-MAX");
```

from what I've read, my problem is that the table matches to this search because the table contains the cell. Here's my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sonoflysander/9gBqU/15

Bonus Points: What I'm going to try to do afterwards, I'd like to pragmatically get the cell immediately next (in this case cell with value "1234") so I can change it's value arbitrarily as well.

As always, any help is much appreciated.

---

Based on gustavohenke's answer, I've abstracted a function which I'll include here for people looking for something a little more generic than my exact scenario.

```
function findString(search, element) {
    search = (typeof search === 'RegExp') ? search : new RegExp('^\\s*' + String(search) + '\\s*$');
    element = (typeof element === 'undefined') ? '*' : element;
    var x = $(element).filter(function () {
        return search.test($(this).text());
    });
    return x;
}
```

method signature:

```
findString(search [, element])
```

`search` can be either a string or a regex, `element` is optional. If not provided it'll search the WHOLE body. For the sake of performance I recommend you specify `element`.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sonoflysander/9gBqU/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var affected = $("td").filter(function() {
  // You should use regex here because you'll likely to receive whitespaces in the .text() call
  return /^\s*Value 1\s*$/.test( $( this ).text() );
}).text( "Value 1.TO THE MAX" );

// Now you apply what you want to what comes after that <td>s
affected.next().text( "I'm next to an awesome <td> affected by my code!" );
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help! I definitely think this is the best answer. I'm updating my question to include the abstracted function for what you've done here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
$("td").filter(function(){
 return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Value 1';
}).text("Value 1.TO THE MAX");
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/9gBqU/21/

To access next `td` you use `.next()` in above code

```
$("td").filter(function(){
 return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Value 1';
}).text("Value 1.TO THE MAX").next('td').text("i am next");
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/9gBqU/27/

Answer (score 1):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/FGyAH/)***

Search through the text, then trim it because the whitespace is what is giving you problems, and then assign matches to the correct value

```
$("td").each(function(){
 if($(this).text().trim() == "Value 1"){
  $(this).text("Value 1.TO THE MAX");   
 }
});
```