# Chrome Extension, JQuery error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'text'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm having a puzzling issue using JQuery in my context scripts. I am attempting to run some JavaScript on facebook, and I keep getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'text'".

In my manifest.json my context script is declared like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["https://*.facebook.com/*"],
    "js": ["jquery.js", "misc.js", "facebook.js"],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at": "document_end"
  },
  //.... there are other pages that are get injected with contexts scrips here as well that aren't having this same issue.
]
```

I'm using JQuery v1.7.1, misc.js has [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779394/jquery-find-text-and-change-single-cell-value) as this:

```
function findString(search, element) {
    element = (typeof element === "undefined") ? "td" : element;
    var x = $(element).filter(function () {
        return new RegExp('^\\s*' + search + '\\s*$').test($(this).text());
    });
    return x;
}
```

from one of my previous questions, and facebook.js has had two different coding attempts, this first one is just regular JQuery:

```
var name = $("a._8_2"); //I did check, and on all my friend's profiles the class "_8_2" appears to be unique every time.
if (name.length){
  var nmTxt = name.text();
  name.text("chupacabra");  
}
```

which was an attempt to target the name on a facebook profile page which is structured like this:

```
<div class="_6-e">
  <h2 class="_6-f">
    <a class="_8_2" href="https://www.facebook.com/profileurlhere">FirstName LastName</a>
  </h2>
</div>
```

This didn't work, I got the error I mentioned and tired finding it with `var name = $("div._6-3");` with the same outcome.
I then tried what I thought would be a very messy workaround:

```
var name = findString(document.title, "a"); //this method is defined in misc.js, see link above
if (name.length){
  var nmTxt = name.text();
  name.text("chupacabra");
}
```

And this still didn't work. I get the same error on `var nmTxt = name.text();` and I cannot figure out why, especially because I'm injecting script very similar to this on other pages (in this very same extension) and those are working as it should be expected.

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Are you sure `findString` returns a JQuery object?  You might just need to wrap it like `$(name).text()`.

Comment: Yes, I am actually fairly sure it does. It has in my other context scripts without issue. That's why I'm all the more confused =Z Here's the [link to the function in my older question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779394/jquery-find-text-and-change-single-cell-value), but for clarity I'll include it in this question.

Comment: Same result if you do `jQuery("a._8_2")`?

Comment: I just attempted that, and yes same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`name` is in your global scope, so it's actually conflicting with [`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.name). `window.name` silently converts its value to a string, which is where your error is coming from:

```
> window.name = $('<a>')
> window.name
"[object Object]"
> window.fooname = $('<a>')
> window.fooname
[<a>​</a>​]
```

So to fix it, either wrap your code in an anonymous function to prevent things from leaking into the global scope:

```
(function() {
  ...
})();
```

Or use a different variable name. I would use the self-executing anonymous function.

Comment: Ah, that's right. I remember other issues with variables named `name`. +1

Comment: Brilliant. I can't believe I didn't realize that myself (I'm stupid). You are what my people call "totally boss".